# PHP compare multiple string

Tags: php

I have a lot of links:

```
http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale.html
http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale1.html
http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale2.html
http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale/exmpale1.html
http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale/exmpale2.html
http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale/exmpale3.html
http://exmpale.com/abcd/exmpale1.html
http://exmpale.com/abcd/exmpale2.html
http://exmpale.com/abcd/exmpale2.html
http://exmpale.com/abcd/exmpale4.html
http://exmpale.com/abc/abc/exmpale1.html
http://exmpale.com/abc/abc/exmpale2.html
http://exmpale.com/abc/abc/exmpale3.html
http://exmpale.com/abc/abc/exmpale4.html
http://exmpale.com/abc/abc/exmpale5.html
```

I use php, i want to get all links like `http://exmpale.com/abc/(*).html` and list it in array.
I'm sorry, I forgot code. code of me

```
$a = array(
    0 => 'http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale.html',
    1 => 'http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale1.html',
    2 => 'http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale2.html',
    3 => 'http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale/exmpale1.html',
    4 => 'http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale/exmpale2.html',
    5 => 'http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale/exmpale3.html',
    6 => 'http://exmpale.com/abcd/exmpale1.html',
    7 => 'http://exmpale.com/abcd/exmpale2.html',
    8 => 'http://exmpale.com/abcd/exmpale2.html',
    9 => 'http://exmpale.com/abcd/exmpale4.html',
    10 => 'http://exmpale.com/abc/abc/exmpale1.html',
    11 => 'http://exmpale.com/abc/abc/exmpale2.html',
    12 => 'http://exmpale.com/abc/abc/exmpale3.html',
    13 => 'http://exmpale.com/abc/abc/exmpale4.html',
    14 => 'http://exmpale.com/abc/abc/exmpale5.html',
);

foreach($a as $k => $v ){
    $abc = preg_match_all('/http\:\/\/exmpale\.com\/abc\/(.*?)\.html/',$v,$b);  
    print_r($b[1]);
}
```

and I want to get the result.

```
$result = array(
  'http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale.html',
  'http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale1.html',
  'http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale2.html');
```

but it took all result, please help me
thanks you.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at loops and substring functions. Start looking into the documentation, start using google for that. Then start your own script, try to solve this yourself. _Then_, if you run into a _specific_ issue with your own code, _then_ is the time to ask here and post your code inside the question. We are not here to do your work for you. We are here to help you with getting your work done.

Comment: sorry, i frogot code of me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you dont provide what kind of data structure the urls are stored in, I assume it's a raw string:

```
$data_raw = "http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale.html
http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale1.html
http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale2.html
http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale/exmpale1.html
http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale/exmpale2.html
http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale/exmpale3.html
http://exmpale.com/abcd/exmpale1.html
http://exmpale.com/abcd/exmpale2.html
http://exmpale.com/abcd/exmpale2.html
http://exmpale.com/abcd/exmpale4.html
http://exmpale.com/abc/abc/exmpale1.html
http://exmpale.com/abc/abc/exmpale2.html
http://exmpale.com/abc/abc/exmpale3.html
http://exmpale.com/abc/abc/exmpale4.html
http://exmpale.com/abc/abc/exmpale5.html";

$urls = explode("\n", $data_raw);

$accept_host = "exmpale.com";
$accept_path = "/abc/";

$filtered_urls = array_filter($urls, function($url) use($accept_host, $accept_path) {
    $parts = parse_url($url);   
    return $parts['host'] == $accept_host
        && strpos($parts['path'], $accept_path) === 0
        && strpos($parts['path'], '/', strlen($accept_path)) === false;
});

printf("<pre>%s</pre>", print_r($filtered_urls, true));
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale.html
    [1] => http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale1.html
    [2] => http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale2.html
)
```

Comment: thanks you. but data in string and I want to get result http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale.html,http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale1.html and http://exmpale.com/abc/exmpale2.html

Comment: I understand that you want each url seperated by a comma. Have a look at the update.

Comment: I just saw your update. The result you are asking for is the array `$filtered_urls`. Have you tried the code?

Comment: and in example it is three link me comment.

Comment: @phuochq Ok, so you will not accept any additional path parameters after /abc/?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the php function preg_match_all and the matched string will get loaded in an array that you supply to the above function as an argument. Please read the PHP manual on preg_match_all and create a regex for your needs. You can test your regex [here](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: i use function preg_match_all   but result not like